# Is it possible to use adodb stream for large files using pre-allocated chunks?

Tags: com, autohotkey, adodb

I'm currently using comobject adodb.stream to grab very large files (multiple gb) from archive.org as an authenticated user and consequently receiving an out of memory error at allocation time.  Is there a way to use adodb.stream to set the chunk size and append/concatenate to the output file?
  Alternative solutions are welcome.
Here I am using AHKscript:

```
file_save_location := save
Overwrite := True
get_site := "https://archive.org/download/file.zip"  ;;multi-gb file
post_site :="https://archive.org/account/login.php"
post_data :="username=" username_str "&password=" password_str "&remember=CHECKED&referer=https://archive.org&action=login&submit=Log in"
WebRequest := ComObjCreate( "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" )
WebRequest.Open("POST", post_site)
WebRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application / zip, application / octet - stream""application / zip, application / octet - stream")
WebRequest.SetRequestHeader("Cookie", "test-cookie=1")
WebRequest.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate,sdch")
WebRequest.Send(post_data)
WebRequest.Open("HEAD",get_site)
WebRequest.Send()
WebRequest.Open("GET",get_site)
WebRequest.Send()
ADODBObj := ComObjCreate( "ADODB.Stream" )
ADODBObj.Type := 1
ADODBObj.Open()
;;ADODBObj.Position := 0  ;;getting warm
ADODBObj.Write( WebRequest.ResponseBody )
ADODBObj.SaveToFile(file_save_location, Overwrite ? 2:1)
ADODBObj.Close()
ADODBObj:=""
WebRequest:=""
```

Comment: There is already a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41241229/692942) to this exact question. Plus [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54311315/692942) in the same vane was only asked 9 days ago, this is getting old.